# HTML page render only part of image

Tags: html, image, iis, rendering

I have a simple html page (in IIS) in which I display the image. The image (image source) is overwritten every minute. In the html page I have done that the page refreshes every minute to load the newer image.

I thought everything was working well for me and as it should. But I found out that about once a day I get stuck rendering an image - I mean that I only see half of that image in an HTML page at a time. When I open the image normally, it is complete.
I can't figure out what this might cause, can you advise me?

Comment: Try to generate new image instead of overwrite it and then update the name of the image inside the html code each time as well, that should work.

Comment: According to your description, it is difficult to reproduce your problem. Under what circumstances do you only render part of the html page?